# Update non-request user information in a Django template and view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

So I have a `ManageUserForm` in forms.py-- it renders correctly but it doesn't pull the right data from the user i'm trying to edit.

In the template, I have a for loop that works correctly

```
{% for tenants in tenants %}
{{ tenants.user }} {{ tenants.type }}
{% endfor %}
```

This template renders the list of objects in the UserProfile. And it does it correctly. The challenge I face is updating the "tenants.type" attribute. Again, the type shows up correctly but I don't know how to update it from this template page.

```
#views.py

def manage_users(request):
tenants = UserProfile.objects.all()

form = ManageUserForm(request.POST or None)

if form.is_valid():
    update = form.save(commit=False)
    update.save()

return render_to_response('manage_users.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))

#forms.py

class ManageUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = UserProfile
         exclude = ('full_name', 'user',)
```

`I think I need to call an instance but I have no idea how to do so for the non-request users AND still follow the pattern for the template. The template basically is a list of users where the request user (staff user) will be able to change the data in the list.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You have one form for one user. You need a `FormSet` if you want to use that form to edit multiple tenants. Editing objects and displaying them are entirely different beasts; dont' confuse them. `formset = modelformset_factory(form=ManageUserForm, queryset=tenants)` May the google-force be with you.

Comment: i got it working.. take a look at what it renders: [link](http://tenantpark.com/manageusers/)... notice it doesn't correlate the users and the form model. Do you know how to change that? Be sure to click username to toggle form.

Comment: you have multiple forms; a formset is supposed to work with a single form and all forms at once. You should be rendering ONE {{ form.management_form }} and the rest of the {% for form in formset %}{{ form }}{% endfor %} in one <form> tag. All of your forms are the first form in the formset. You should rewrite your template loop  to iterate through formset forms instead of tenant objects. The tenant object can be accessed through {{ form.instance }}.

Comment: that's awesome. didn't even know that was possible. Do you know why I'm getting an extra field? [link](http://tenantpark.com/manageusers/)

Comment: I converted my comments to an answer. In short, pass `extra=0` to the formset factory function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one form for one user. You need a FormSet if you want to use that form to edit multiple tenants. Editing objects and displaying them are entirely different beasts; dont' confuse them.

```
formset = modelformset_factory(form=ManageUserForm, queryset=tenants)
```

---

Update:
You should have one `{{ form.management_form }}` and the rest of the `{% for form in formset %}{{ form }}{% endfor %}` in one `<form>` tag. All of your forms are the first form in the formset.

You should rewrite your template loop to iterate through formset forms instead of tenant objects. The tenant object can be accessed through `{{ form.instance }}`

---

Update 2:
You have an extra form because you probably haven't passed in the `extra=0` parameter to the `modelformset_factory` function. These forms are typically used to add/edit data; thus it has support for adding N blank forms for creating.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you again Yuji. YOu've been super helpful.